# Card to card transactions

Tags: credit-card, money-transfer, wire-transfer

I have seen that some companies can send you money to your credit card. What type of transaction is it? I guess it is not wire transfer. And can this be achieved from your local bank? ( I live in europe) Or it is done through Visa or Mastercard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With change in technology and regulations, quite a few clearing systems provide an ability to directly credit a credit card. In Europe Sepa transactions allow one to credit a credit card.

The service would be offered by Local bank rather than Visa or Master Card

Answer (score 0):

I would presume this goes entirely through the credit card network rather than the banking network. I am *guessing* that it's essentially the same operation as if you had returned something purchased on a card to the store for credit, but I'm not sure whether it really looks like a vendor credit to the network or if it is marked as a different type of transaction.